# how to Merge remote-tracking branch 'caffe/master' into HEAD ?

Tags: python, git, github, cpu

I'm using the `Ubuntu 14.04` without `CPU` and i want to run this code : https://github.com/xinleipan/py-faster-rcnn-with-new-dataset , 
in Step 1, if i do `git merge -X theirs caffe/master` he print :

GNU nano 2.2.6                       File: /home/brm17/Desktop/py-faster-rcnn/.git/modules/caffe-fast-rcnn/MERGE_MSG

```
Merge remote-tracking branch 'caffe/master' into HEAD

# Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
# especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
#
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts
# the commit.
```

what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

That's the editor that is opened so that you can write the commit message. That means the merge went well, no conflicts. Just set the comment, save the file and quit and the merge revision should be done.

Comment: What do I do?? Do I save only?

Comment: Yep, just set the right comment at the top, save and quit